# Angular testing: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null

Tags: angular, integration-testing, karma-runner, angular-routerlink

I am new in Angular testing and at the moment I am trying to test this piece of code but I'm getting an error concerning the event raised on the DOM:

```html
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let user of users">
  <a class="test-link"[routerLink]="['/detail', user.id]">
    {{user.userName}}
  </a>
</li>
```

The Test file:

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [AdminComponent, UserDetailComponent],
    imports: [HttpClientModule,RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
      {path:'detail/:id',
        component: UserDetailComponent}],
    )],
    providers: [UserService, AuthService]
  })
    .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  router = TestBed.get(Router);
  location = TestBed.get(Location);

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AdminComponent);
  debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();

});

it('test demands redirection', fakeAsync(() => {

  debugElement
    .query(By.css('.test-link'))
    .nativeElement.click();

  tick();

  expect(location.path()).toBe('/detail/testing/1');

}));
```

Why is click event on the native element is null?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because when this test will run, your users array will be empty, and hence there will be no element in html with `.test-link` selector.

Before clicking the element, you should fill the users array and let angular run the change detection so that your anchor tag is available when you click on it.

**Code:**

```js
it('test demands redirection', fakeAsync(() => {

  component.users = [
    // fill it with user objects
  ];

  fixture.detectChanges();

  debugElement
    .query(By.css('.test-link'))
    .nativeElement.click();

  tick();

  expect(location.path()).toBe('/detail/testing/1');

}));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but can i fill it with dummy data?

Comment: Yes, you can fill it with any data you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error - "TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null" - and found that I had copy-pasted the same html element id into multiple locations. I ensured